# Seeding values into asp:controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm confused over this issue in my code and hoping that someone sees something that I'm missing here. The top part of this works perfectly but the same basic code being executed on two other similar fields directly below fails to inject the value into the text box even though I've striped off all possible things I could think of that might suppress the fuction from working.

I'm not getting any errors of any kind and when I debug it the values are being assigned as expected.  Just nothing is showing up in the text boxes as I would expect.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    <%-- This part works fine --%>
    TextBox uname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitByTbx");
    if (uname != null)
        uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

    TextBox udate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitDTTbx");
    if (udate != null)
        udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    <%-- This part Fails to stuff the values into the TextBoxes --%>
    TextBox uuname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredByTextBox");
    if (uname != null)
        uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

    TextBox uudate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredTextBox");
    if (udate != null)
        udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Anything anyone sees that would be helpful would be greatly appreciated. I've been glairing at it for the last several hours and getting no where.

---

Final solution based on response provide looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox uname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitByTbx");
     if (uname != null)
        uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

   TextBox udate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitDTTbx");
     if (udate != null)
        udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

   TextBox uuname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredByTextBox");
     if (uuname != null)
        uuname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

    TextBox uudate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredTextBox");
      if (uudate != null)
         uudate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: what does your .aspx file look like in terms of the ID names of the 2 that are not working can you show the Markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a typo?  uuname vs uname and uudate vs udate?

```
TextBox **uuname** = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredByTextBox");
    if (**uname** != null)
        **uname**.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

    TextBox **uudate** = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredTextBox");
    if (**udate** != null)
        **udate**.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Thank you thank you Thank you!  I was reusing the earlier code and just added a extra u and neglected to add it to the two other positions in each of the clauses! 
I figured another set of eyes on it would see what I was missing!

Comment: Obviously, if one never use abbreviated names, it won't have such problems. Well, it would be easier to see the problem after cut & paste.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code. This should teach a lesson about copy and paste. It is very easy to miss something.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
<%-- This part works fine --%>
TextBox uname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitByTbx");
if (uname != null)
    uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

TextBox udate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("SubmitDTTbx");
if (udate != null)
    udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

<%-- This part Fails to stuff the values into the TextBoxes --%>
TextBox uuname = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredByTextBox");
if (uname != null)
    // correct from uname to uuname
    uuname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

TextBox uudate = (TextBox)AddItemFv.Row.FindControl("AssetEnteredTextBox");
if (udate != null)
    //Corrected from udate to uudate
    uudate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```